# PHP: Prevent cross-site submission of a form to my script

Tags: php

I can't seem to find any answer to this on the web, but how can I be sure a $_POST variable or form was submitted from my site as opposed to just any old site. Is there a way to filter this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require a secret, user-specific token in all form submissions (as a hidden input) and side-effect URLs (in query strings).

If you use sessions,  you can generate a token on creation of a session and store it in the session data.

Comment: Like this? <?php $_SESSION['token'] = md5(3286832ddsd); ?> <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo md5(3286832ddsd); ?>" /> then on receiving page put <?php if ($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) { echo 'It\'s legit!'; }

Comment: Yes — except you want to use something random (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: Oh, and there is no need to md5 it *each time*. Just once will do (and that's only to make it a nice ASCII string for URIs)

Comment: this is not the safe solution because someone copy the hidden value and send this hidden tag with same name and value ,at that time also it makes the checking as true. please check the http_referrer or make the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in htaccess

Comment: @karthikpyrate — It is safe. While it doesn't stop someone who can submit the form from submitting the form with different data (and *nothing* can prevent that) it does stop a third party from copying the form to their site. While they could copy the value of the token, the value they put in their form would not match the one in the user's session, so the server would reject it.

Comment: @karthikpyrate — The referer is trivial to spoof. Access-Control-Allow-Origin can only *weaken* security (and only relates to third parties *reading* data with JavaScript anyway) .

Comment: @Quentin- ok, the session create in the form page, first they comes to the  form page, that time session will be setted from they click the form page, so they know session will be setted then they submit the form from their site with the same session token with same name  , the site only check the posted token with already created session, this time, both values are same, so what we do?

Comment: @karthikpyrate — Nothing. You're already trusting the user. They are using their own credentials, and the CSRF token shows they aren't being launched at your site by an untrusted third party. There's not much you can do about attacks from people you trust using their own credentials (even if you could prevent them from submitting data from another site, they could just modify your form in their DOM Inspector). You can defend against third parties tricking your users into submitting bad data though.

Comment: @quentin-- i am not talking about the user credentials, just think, user session not setted but you display something using post method, so how can you prevent that thing without user's credentials

Comment: The CSRF token doesn't need the user to be logged in to function, sessions work fine for anonymous users. It's just really rare that you would care about CSRF for anything that an anonymous user could access.

Answer (score 0):

To add more safeguard, you should also assign an allow period (like an hour) to expire session/token